# script to untar and move files to a folder

Tags: python, shell

I'm not much of a *nix guy, but for this operation I need to use the *nix compute. Here is excerpt of the console log, and I was wondering if this can be automated?

```
unar file.tgz
cd file
unar second_file.tar
cd usr/path/123/kernel
mv * ~/usr/path/567
```

Comment: u can put those in a text file said cmd.csh, then `source cmd.csh`

Answer (score 1):

- Tar represents tape archives.
- It is most commonly used tape drive backup command.
- It allows you to commonly collect a collection of file and place them into highly compressed archive file commonly called tarball,gzip,bzip in Linux.

the command you are looking for is

**tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz**

this will untar the content of file in the corrent directory

if you want to untar it in a differnet directory then you should use -C flag

**tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz -C path_to_directory**

if your file has only .tar extension then you should run the command

tar -xvf filename.tar

- Extract a tar.gz

  - x –  Extract files
  - v – Verbose, print the file names as they are extracted one by one
  - z – The file is a “gzipped” file
  - f – Use the following tar archive for the operation

if you want to do using a python script you can do as -

```
import tarfile
import os
tar = tarfile.open("test.tar.gz")
os.chdir("pathwhereyouwanttoextract")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Comment: I'm looking to automate the commands to replicate the console activity.

Comment: How is this helpful in shell or python to convert this to an automated process?